# Can't find a div that exists with 'inspect element' while scraping a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a python script which downloads an html page. I'm looking for this div:

```
<data-a-target="clip-thumbnail-link"
```

And that div is there when I inspect element on the webpage I see it. But its not showing up in my print statement in my script

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

BASE_URL = "https://www.twitch.tv/lethalfrag/clips"

def get_category_links(section_url):
    html = urlopen(section_url).read()    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")    
    print(soup)     

get_category_links(BASE_URL)
```

Comment: Sounds like that element is injected into the page contents via javascript, based on some event -- mouseover, mouse click, or simple timer.

Comment: You probably want to read up about Selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search for the inspected element in the page source, you can see that it is missing. This tells us that JavaScript is modifying the page after it loads. `urllib` or `requests` can't run the JavaScript code. So, you'll have to use `Selenium`.

For installation and demo, read this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

You need to use [explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) in order to get the element you are looking for.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.twitch.tv/lethalfrag/clips')
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'clips-cards ')))
except TimeoutException:
    print('Page timed out after 10 secs.')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.quit()
print(soup.find('a', {'data-a-target': 'clip-thumbnail-link'})['href'])
```

Output:

```
https://clips.twitch.tv/RealIgnorantHeronVoteYea
```

Comment: Trying the above code for the website "https://www.usana.com", (href visible in inspection but not visible in page source) but doesn't seem to work. I need the href whose text contains the word 'contact'. Can you please help !!